# Python game on android image does not fill screen size

Tags: android, python, pygame

I am using pygames for android to write a small game. 
Therefore I request a screen of the size 960x540:

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
background = pygame.image.load("floor.png").convert()
backgroundrect = background.get_rect()
```

and in the main loop I draw a background image of the same size:

```
screen.blit(background, backgroundrect)
```

On my development machine everything is correct since the created window matches the requested size.
What I get when I run on android is my background image centered in a window with different aspect ratio. This would not be so bad but in the space where no image should be drawn I see random garbage drawn. I can even fill the background with black beforehand and still see garbage.

Somehow the draw of the background image also draws in the space outside of the aspect ratio?

The bug is also described here: http://pygame.renpy.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=624&p=4915#p4915 which contains a video showing the effect.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is caused by a wrong window size.
You should look into pygame.display.Info (http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.Info) to get the screen resolution.

See this for more details: http://pygame.renpy.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=92#p265

You obviously have to consider this when blitting, as rather than the PyGame window being stretched to fit a larger screen, the PyGame window itself is being made larger.

Comment: So do I always need to create a screen with the same aspect ratio as the display? What definitively works is to have a bigger or smaller screen and everything is automatically scaled.

Comment: I believe so, yes. The only time I've messed with Pygame for Android was a little test on my own device, so I did not try with multiple resolutions. Have you tried set PyGame to fullscreen? It will stretch the game, but it might work.

Comment: I tried but this only seems to be supported on x11. The beauty of requesting a specific size is that pygame handles all screen coordinate translations for me. And it works nicely except for garbage drawn in the letterbox part.